# Laravel: Can't retrieve the old files uploaded to storage

Tags: php, laravel, centos

I have problem regarding deleted files to my storage.

Why It happens to my production laravel project after a long weeks the uploaded files from the storage is deleted and can't view it to the storage and to my public storage.

This happen already almost 5 times, and I don't know which is wrong. The server or my codes. I don't know where to configure it out.. that happens to my live website... I hope someone can help me to solve the problem this..

**Centos 7 is our server**

**Only the uploaded file is in there however the old is gone.**

1. All images removed
2. All pdf files removed

Can I have your suggestion to find out what's going on to the project..?

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: where you uploaded old file? means directory?

Comment: all files upload to root storage, how i retrieve it is to get in public storage.

Comment: in my root storage. all files is gone.

Comment: create new folder under you-project-folder\public\ this directory instead of storage folder because laravel protecting public directory

Comment: the problem is why the files is deleted from my root storage.?

Comment: I should not be happen. don't know how it is auto deleted. may be there is a fault in your code or someone is deleted

Comment: yes and should no be happen. in my codes has no delete script .. only update files have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181052/discussion-between-rahul-pawar-and-devge).